# Convert Encoding.UTF8.GetByte(jsonContent) to php expression

Tags: c#, php

I have below expression

```
jsonContent = {"name":"john"}

byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetByte(jsonContent);
```

How can I wire the same expression in **PHP**

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it's working fine for me.

```
utf8_encode(json_encode(array("name"=>"john")));
```

Any other suggestions would be welcome.